# Ionic modal with state

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there any way to make an [ionic modal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/) have a ui router nested state with multiple modal pages?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are describing a wizard, A model that has multiple pages (or steps).  Because Ionic and AngularJS go hand in hand with each other you can use some of the pre-built AngularJS components to achieve this, here is a link to a few:

https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard

https://github.com/simpulton/angularjs-wizard

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not doing that because I have tried it in the past and in the end I realized that it wasn't really practical. What you could do is, add:

```
ng-include src="'your-template.html'" ng-controller="yourTemplateController">
```

Now you have a view and a controller associated with it. All that is left to is, make the URL change. This can be done by using `location.hash`, or setting `$stateParams` and checking for it using `$watch`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ionic wizard plugin, which although it is designed for wizard like steps, will pretty much provide a set of linked modal pages which share state, which should meet your needs.

http://arielfaur.github.io/ionic-wizard/

It also has nice features such as preventing progression in a wizard until fields are filled out etc.